# What does in between them mean?

Tags: interpretation

> An applicant seeking registration to act as a trustee shall have in its employment a minimum of two persons who, **between them**, have atleast five years experience in activities related to securitisation and atleast **one among** them shall have a professional qualification in law from any university or institution recognised by the Central Government or any State Government or a foreign university.

What does in between them mean in the above statement do both the employee should have 5 years experience each or the experience jointly be of 5 years.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it means is that when you add together the total experience of  both employees, it must be equal to or greater than 5 years.

So Employee A and B can have experience such that one has 1 year and the other has 4 or one has 2 and the other 3 or one has Zero and the other has 5 (debatable... if both employees need experience this might be out of the question).  They could work the same calendar years and count them as separate years of experience.